# Extract columns from unordered data in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning scala-spark and want to know how can we extract required columns from an unordered data based on column name? Details below-

**Input Data: RDD[Array[String]]**

```
id=1,country=USA,age=20,name=abc
name=def,country=USA,id=2,age=30
name=ghi,id=3,age=40,country=USA
```

Required Output:

```
Name,id
abc,1
def,2
ghi,3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have `RDD[Array[String]]` then you can get the desired data as

You can define a case class as

```
case class Data(Name: String, Id: Long)
```

Then parse each line to `case class`

```
val df = rdd.map( row => {
  //split the line and convert to map so you can extract the data
  val data = row.split(",").map(x => (x.split("=")(0),x.split("=")(1))).toMap
  Data(data("name"), data("id").toLong)
})
```

convert to Dataframe and display

```
df.toDF().show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+---+
|Name|Id |
+----+---+
|abc |1  |
|def |2  |
|ghi |3  |
+----+---+
```

Here is full code to read the file

```
case class Data(Name: String, Id: Long)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("xyz").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("path to file ")

  val df = rdd.map(row => {
    val data = row.split(",").map(x => (x.split("=")(0), x.split("=")(1))).toMap
    Data(data("name"), data("id").toLong)
  })

  df.toDF().show(false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shankar! I tried it, gives following error even after i moved case class out of the calling method- No TypeTag available for Data. Please help.Thanks!